# iOS add overlay to entire MapView

Tags: ios, swift

How can I add gray overlay to entire `MapView`?

On the center of the map I will have `MKCircle()` so `UIView` above `MapView` is not the solution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDxUc.png

Comment: Why will an `UIView` above the MapView not work?

Comment: Because then all of the map is gray. But I want to have a circle with certain radius in the center with normal color.

Comment: You could also make the `UIView` have a hole, by implementing custom drawing.

Comment: I added image for reference. But is this possible with zooming? Then when I zoom i have to redraw the entire view? And how can I determine the radius? If the radius is 1km then I must show the circle with 1km radius on map.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. And yes you will have to redraw the view. It's not easy but doable.

Comment: I will try your approach. Thank you for help.